# Lua, find string.match , take second variable and do a hex and then match it

Tags: string, lua, hexdump

1. I get a string from a message /whisper
2. The string contains password:name:nameInHex
3. I want to find the first variable in the string and compare it with the password trigger and if the trigger == first variable in the string then continue to nr4 in the list.
4. I want to find the second variable in the string, name and convert it to hex.
5. I want to compare name with nameInHex and if it is true, then continue to invite the person to by using a chat command /invite

Comment: That's a lot of tasks, did you try anything yourself, at all? Do it and ask specific questions if you have problems then.

Comment: the addon works fine, its just that i want to add more to it, right now i can take a whisper and it will check if the string matches and then invite. What i would like to have help with is how the code is for Reading a string and then taking out parts in it as nr2 in my list is. But yes, ill dig into woodlumhoodlum's message instead.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string when you reach each colon, and store them their respective variables.
Then have your logic to process each once you have them stored in a variable

http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin

Answer (score 0):

Start with

```
password,name,nameInHex=mystring:match("^(.-):(.-):(.-)$")
```